# Calling uitableview while clicking uitextfield-Data not displaying -iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextfield

I want to display data in `uitableview` when the particular `uitextfield` is tapped. I am not getting the data in `taleview`. Please check the below and help me.

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";



     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;



    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Bold" size:20]];


     if (ethnicityField.tag == 1)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

 if (languageField.tag == 2)
    {
         cell.textLabel.text = [langData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    }
```

Here, when I click on the first `textfield` it shows the empty table and crashes.
It's not taking the exact tag value. Please help.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    int row = 0;
    if (ethnicityField.tag == 1)
    {
        row = [data count];
    }
    if (languageField.tag == 2)
    {
         row =   [langData  count];
    }
    return row;
}
```

Crash report:
Actually I have 2 arrays, one with 5 values and another with 11 values, the problem is both `textfield` takes first array and if I select the 5th object in second `textfield` it shows the following error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 9 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
```

Comment: Can you add the crash log?

Comment: What is the error ?  Can you show numberOfRowsInSection method ?

Comment: @Justafinger :Added Please check

Comment: @Ricky:crash report added.Please check.

Comment: What ethnicityField is? I can't get what this condition  if (ethnicityField.tag == 1) stands for. What ethnicityField.tag depends on?

Comment: From your error, you are trying to get number 10th object (index 9) but your array only contain 5 objects (object 0 to object 4). I think other developers here can help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe ethnicityField and languageField always have the same tag so numberOfRowsInSection always returns `[data count];`

What you could do is checking whether a textfield is active when you display your table.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    int row = 0;
    if ([ethnicityField isFirstResponder])
    {
        row = [data count];
    }
    else if ([languageField isFirstResponder])
    {
         row =   [langData  count];
    }
    return row;
}
```

Comment: yep your right.Both the field taking the value from data array.Hoe to fix this?